# Is it possible to detect/assign faces in iPhoto for iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-iphoto, photos.app

With the new iPhoto out for both the iPhone and iPad, I was wondering whether it allows face detection and assignment on iOS or is it still OS X-only feature?

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/can-i-tag-iphoto-faces-on-ios

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, because the question you're referring to was asked in Dec '10 and iPhoto was not available on iOS back then. Thilo should phrase it differently as what he's asking is whether he can do it from Photos app which is synced with iPhoto.

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the date. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhoto for iOS doesn't do facial recognition nor tagging.

Answer (score 0):

A search on the [Apple Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&product=&q=iOS%20iPhoto%20faces&src=support_site.kbase.search.searchresults) reveals several articles on Faces for iPhoto on iOS. However, all of them have been deleted, so I suppose Faces didn't make it into the current version and will follow soon in a next release.